# Increment id when insert row javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a HTML table like this:

```
<table id="dataTableLapis">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="prova1">
            <td>
                <select id="uff_prot" name="lapis_ufficio[]"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input "type="text" id="lapis_vis" name="lapis_vis[]" size="30">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="lapis_ufficio" name="lapis_gruppo_mov[]"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this HTML Button :

```
<input type="button" value="Aggiungi ufficio protocollo" onClick="addRow('dataTableLapis')" />
```

That runs this javascript:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 5){
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 5.");
    }
}
```

My problem is: when the new rows are inserted the id are always the some

> row1 - id="uff_prot" - id="lapis_vis" - id="lapis_ufficio"
>
> row2 - id="uff_prot" - id="lapis_vis" - id="lapis_ufficio"

I want this result:

> row1 - id="uff_prot1" - id="lapis_vis1" - id="lapis_ufficio1"
>
> row2 - id="uff_prot2" - id="lapis_vis2" - id="lapis_ufficio2"

How can I do this?

Comment: Keep a counter variabele, and insert it?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the line with row.setAttribute under the declaration of row variable.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   if(rowCount < 5){
       var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
           row.setAttribute('id',"lapis_ufficio"+rowCount);
       var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
       for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
           var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
           newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
       }
  }else{
     alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 5.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this piece of code doesn't work:

```
var els = newRow.querySelectorAll("[id]");

    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els.id += rowCount;
```

the select id and input id are the some, change only the tr id